# Data hazard in MIPS-like pipeline architecture

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Let the following pipeline architecture:

> 1. FETCH
> 2. DECODE - READ REGISTERS
> 3. READ MEMORY
> 4. ALU
> 5. STORE/READ MEMORY
> 6. WRITE BACK - STORE TO REGISTERS

We basically added a phase which enables us to read data from memory before ALU phase.

Consider the following new commands:

```
lwPointer $2, imm($3) # $2:= Memory[Memory[$3] + imm]`   
swPointer $2, imm($3) # Memory[Memory[$3] + imm] := $2
```

Let the following program:

```
1. add $3 $2 $1   
2. lwPointer $1, 0($3)
3. sw $7 0($3)
```

Why there's no data-hazard between for command `#3`? As I see it, `$3` decoded by command `#3` isn't updated.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you. Since `$3` is altered by command#1, there is definitely a data hazard for both command#2 and #3. What is your actual question ?

Comment: Well, I've seen a solution which claimed there's no data-hazard for command #3 and I wanted to validate it here.

Comment: Well, no matter how I look at it, there is a data hazard for `$3` on cmd#2 and #3. Maybe the point was that the new STEP 3 doesn't introduce additional hazards ? It would be only for this case, since it does introduce hazards if you swap cmd#2 and #3. Or maybe we're both crazy or stupid. Is there any comment on this "solution" that would help to clarify ?

Comment: For command #3, the value of 0+$3 (i.e., the store address) is not needed until the beginning of stage 5.